# Azure and Office 365 with same login

Tags: office365, azure, microsoft-account

Since Windows 10 was released my environment starts behaving strange. I have to accounts at Microsoft:

1. A Microsoft Account foo@sample.com
2. An O365 acccount foo@sample.com

Until last wednesday everything worked fine. I could for instance open an IE session and log in to my Azure Portal and the O365 Portal with those  credentials. Now my O365 account seems to be something like a Microsoft Account which is no Microsoft Account. It seems like they created an AAD account out of it and now I have an organizational and Microsoft account with the same login.

So now Azure Portal states that foo@sample.com is not a valid Microsoft Account when I already logged in the same browser session to O365. I now don't know what the right exit is.

I needed the Microsoft Account because it existed long before the Office 365 account and there was no warning when I created the O365 with the same name.

I've tried to change the mail-alias on my Microsoft Account but that doesn't change anything on the behavior.

Answer (score 1):

There used to be two different logon portals you could use depending on whither you had a Microsoft account or a work account (Azure AD).  Microsoft has rolled out changes to their system integrating these into a single logon page.

You see this now when on the login screen "**Work or school, or personal Microsoft account**"

(the "Work or school" account used to be known as an "organization" account - it exists in Azure AD and is used by business-focused Microsoft Online Services like Office 365, Azure and Dynanmics CRM; the Microsoft account is what has grown out of Windows Live IDs, typically used for consumer-facing services, but also for logging on to Windows PCs)

However when you enter your credentials if the alias exists for both a work and a Microsoft account you should be presented with the option to select which one you want to use
[image]

If you are not seeing this - try clearing your browser cache and cookies, and navigating directly to https://login.microsoftonline.com/  and then inputting just your email and tabbing into the password box - it should redirect to the page above so you can select which account to use.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I see this option. What I in fact want is to merge these two accounts to one. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: That is not possible